# HTTP Post request to aws ec2 directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/ denied

Tags: apache, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp

I am trying to make a post request to http://localhost/donate/payment.php".
It works fine when I run the application locally

However when I change the URL to

"http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/**opt/lampp/htdocs/donate/payment.php**"

I get  page not found error. I can guarantee that the file is present in the location.

I have tried several things like changing the permission of the the **/opt** file recursively to 777. Also tried changing the apache server port default port from 80.

I even tried placing a .htacces file inside the donate folder to access the server. the contents are

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com 

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/WebProjectFolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /WebProjectFolder/$1
```

All attempts have failed. Is there anything else I am missing here. I have installed bitnami parse server and I am able to access that by http in the browser. It is present in the folder /apps in the root folder.

Does AWS override any security permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`is your document root, shouldn't the URL be `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/donate/payment.php`?

You might also want to verify a couple of things:

1. Make sure your security policy has its inbound port 80 open to the public (or where you'll be visiting from)
2. Assuming you're using Apache `httpd`, make sure it accepts connections on the external interface or all interfaces (e.g. `Listen 80`, `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried that. Unfortunately, It did not work

Comment: Please see expanded answer.

Comment: Tried that did not work either. I have got multiple http.conf files. Will that create a problem

Comment: You should identify the right `httpd.conf` to modify, and restart `httpd` after any setting changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you actually get an error from your *Apache* server, the issue has nothing to do with *AWS*. If there were misconfigured *security groups* or *NACL*, you'd never reach port 80 (*http*).

Second, never **ever** `chmod -R 777`, not only can you break your app behavior, but also, especially with *PHP*, you just opened security risks. Yes, this doesn't matter until your instance becomes part of a botnet and starts sending spam.

At a glance, I would say your Apache configuration lacks something, like a `VirtualHost` "any":

```
# from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like your default location points to another directory, possibly the default one.